# .NET 4.0 + XNA 4.0 - Content.RootDirectory not working when given an absolute path?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, xna

How would I go about making Content.RootDirectory an absolute path, so that I could load from somewhere other than Content?

I don't think I'm meant to, because this is giving non-existant errors:

```
Content.RootDirectory = "C:\\Users\\pc user\\Desktop\\";

outputFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("SpriteFont1");
```

SpriteFont1.spritefont definitly exists in C:\Users\pc user\Desktop. No doubt about it.

It is a valid spritefont file, and I'd just moved it from Content, where it was working fine, onto my Desktop, where it's.. Er.. Not.

I do need to be able to do this, but if you actually cannot load Texture2Ds and SpriteFonts etc from an absolute path using Content.Load I'm willing to install a library or something to do it.

I hope I've just made a 'silly mistake' and that it will work.

Error is:

```
ContentLoadException was unhandled

Error loading "SpriteFont1". File not found.
```

Comment: try this link for examples on how to get started .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-7-xna-api(MSADS.20).aspx to find many examples using C# type C# Content.RootDirectory into Google Search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed the Texture2D.FromStream method. I'll post for future reader's enjoyment:

```
public Stream stream;
Texture2D x;

stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\pc user\\Desktop\\faceGuy.png");
x = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, stream);

spriteBatch.Draw(x, new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32), Color.White);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you moving your SpriteFont's and Textures to your desktop when it worked perfectly fine in Content?

And I think to move Content's location you would have to go backwards.

```
Content.RootDirectory = "Content\\..\\..";
```

And also don't forget that not all computers use C: for their main file directory, unless this is only for your personal use, then you obviously do.

And was the spritefont imported into your Content Project. If it is on your desktop now it is most likely not imported anymore, at least not where it is aware of.

And here is an answer to a similar question. The picture link no longer works but the answer might help you out. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/9748/11721

Comment: I'm making a way of developing games, an XNA, I think it's called a wrapper, so using Content isn't an option unfortunately. :(